# I'm not getting why they put 0 there as when we do char(i-1). It should show some error

Tags: java, string, algorithm, char

**Sample Input 0**

aaabccddd

**Sample Output 0**

abd

***and I find this solution***

```
static String super_reduced_string(String s) 
{
    int i;


    String s1="Empty String";

    StringBuffer ss = new StringBuffer(s);

    for(i = 1; i < ss.length(); i++) {
        if(ss.charAt(i) == ss.charAt(i-1)) {
            ss.deleteCharAt(i);
            ss.deleteCharAt(i-1);
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    String str2 = ss.toString();
    if(ss.length() == 0) 
        return s1;
    else 
        return str2;
}
```

I don't understand why `i = 0` in code because when the line `ss.CharAt(i - 1)` is run the compiler should show some error but code is working fine.

Comment: I don't see a clear problem statement.  Is the current output what you want?  In any case, what is the logic behind this output?

Comment: i want to know why they put i=0?

Comment: Have you tried running the code? It is semantically correct, therefore the *compiler* won't show an error. But when it runs it may very well exit with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 2):

Basically that is an ugly way to restart the looping.

This makes sure that after deleting chars, the loop starts from 0 again.

For the record: this is bad practice, and that whole code example is like on big "don't write such code" statement. Those few lines use *bad naming*, they are misleading, hiding intent instead of communicating it.

Comment: Will the loop re-evaluate ss.length() each time ?

Comment: @Sylvain probably

Comment: Another problem in the code is that the loop originally doesn't start from 0, but from 1. It is unreadable, bug-prone, and I 100% agree with "don't write such code".

Comment: Yes, this code is poorly written. besides all that, it doesn't need to restart from zero: it could continue from i-2 (unless i == 1)

Answer (score 1):

`i = 0` is set when the `if` condition is met, then the `for` loop increases `i` by 1 so `i = 1`.

Therefore when `ss.CharAt(i - 1)` is reached it finds the `char` at position 0.

Answer (score 0):

`for(i = 1; i < ss.length(); i++)` increments `i` before the next iteration, so `i=0` at the bottom off the loop. AS It comes back to the  `for(i = 1; i < ss.length(); i++)` then `i++` is applied so

```
if(ss.charAt(i) == ss.charAt(i-1))
```

becomes

```
if(ss.charAt(1) == ss.charAt(1-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop above is equivalent to:

```
i = 1;
while (i < ss.length()) {
    if(ss.charAt(i) == ss.charAt(i-1)) {
        ss.deleteCharAt(i);
        ss.deleteCharAt(i-1);
        i = 0;
    }
    i++;
}
```

As you can see i is incremented immediately after it's set to zero.

That said, the code is poorly written (see answer from @GhostCat); it could have been written like this:

```
static String super_reduced_string(String s) 
{
    int i;

    String s1="Empty String";

    StringBuilder ss = new StringBuilder();

    for(char c: s.toCharArray()) {
        int len = ss.length();
        if(len == 0 || c != ss.charAt(len-1)) {
            ss.append(c);
        } else {
            ss.deleteCharAt(len-1);
        }
    }
    String str2 = ss.toString();
    if(ss.length() == 0) 
        return s1;
    else 
        return str2;
}
```